# img class isn't working

Tags: html, css, image, class

I can't figure this out.  Been out of the design game a while and can't get this dang image to align to the right.  Here is my coding for the image.

HTML

```
<a href=“www.facebook.com”><img src="images/logo.png" class=“logo” /></a>
```

CSS

```
img.logo {
    float: right;
}
```

It applies float to all images if I just put

```
img {
    float: right;
}
```

but it won't recognize the class.

Here is the FULL CSS code

```
body {
    background-image:url(images/mainbg.jpg);
}

#container {
    width: 940px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 166px;
    bottom: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: -4px;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 115px;
}

#content {
    background-image: url(images/bodybg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    width: 940px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#footer {
    background-image: url(images/footbg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 940px;
    height: 66px;
    margin-top: -60px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

img.logo {
     float: right;
}

a {color: #fff;}
a:visted {color:#fff;}
a:hover {color: #555;}
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: why dont just `.logo`? if the `.logo` just for the image?

Comment: Looks like you've got the wrong double-quotes in your HTML. Try single quotes, or if it's just one class, no quotes at all. Your `src` attribute is correct, but your class attribute and the `href` attribute both have the wrong quotes.

Comment: @MikeW is right, you have the wrong quotation marks, I tried it and it worked for me just changing the quotation marks.

Comment: @MikeW is correct in saying that the quotation marks are the incorrect type, but they should still be double quotes rather than single quotes.

Comment: @jshthornton Actually, the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) allows attributes to be empty or delimited with no quotes, single quotes or double quotes. The HTML4 specification says something similar.

Comment: @MikeW whilst it might say that, in general, most HTML coding standard and conventions agree to use double quotes, regardless to whether they are needed or not. See https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml#HTML_Quotation_Marks

Answer (score 5):

It's simple, just change your quotation marks:

HTML:

```
<a href="www.facebook.com"><img src="http://placekitten.com/200/400" class="logo" /></a>
```

CSS:

```
.logo{
    float: right;
}
```

[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/68283/)

Answer (score 0):

okay so here is the problem. you need to use the proper `quotation mark` in your case you have use it in wrong manner.

The second and most important thing is you are floating the `img` to right; which doesn't make any impact on `a` tag.

Have a look at the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/hehicoqi/1/edit)** here.

So what you need to do, instead of floating the `img` element you must float the `a` tag. which is good for SEO practice. Check the **[New DEMO](http://jsbin.com/piwedisu/1/edit)** link.

Comment: Quotations fixed it.  Except my keyboard only has those quotes so now I guess I copy and paste all quotes.  lol.

Comment: if by copying its solves your problem then you must do it.. if my solution is enough and solves your problem you may accept this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe give this a try

```
//CSS
.RightImage{
width:100%;
height:200px;
right:0;
position:absolute;
}
//HTML
<div class="RightImage"><a href=“www.facebook.com”><img src="images/logo.png" class=“logo” /></a></div>
```

Comment: This misses the problem, which is that the quotes are wrong so the class attribute isn't being picked up properly

Answer (score -1):

```
.logo img{
    float: right;
}
```

simply use this

Comment: This misses the problem, which is that the quotes are wrong so the class attribute isn't being picked up properly.

Answer (score -1):

Replace...

```
img.logo {
    float: right;
}
```

with

```
.logo img{
    float: right;
}
```

This will right align image of class logo.

Comment: This misses the problem, which is that the quotes are wrong so the class attribute isn't being picked up properly